# need help in understanding the deadlock

Tags: mysql, mariadb, innodb

I got the deadlock below when running `insert into` statements. What's the possible cause of this and how you suggest to solve it?

```
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
2020-01-01 06:56:20 0x7fbfa9c4f700
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 3770369752, ACTIVE 0 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 3 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 4 row lock(s), undo log entries 3
MySQL thread id 583875, OS thread handle 140464586606336, query id 1343761255 172.16.0.73 be update
INSERT INTO hourly_creative_stats (date_hour, account_id, campaign_id, creative_id,placement_id, bid) VALUES (date_format(utc_timestamp(),'%Y-%m-%d %H'),3,164807,123318,42667,1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE bid=bid+values(bid)
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 1558 page no 909823 n bits 120 index PRIMARY of table `ubimo`.`hourly_creative_stats` trx id 3770369752 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 12 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 22; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 5; hex 99a5426000; asc   B` ;;
 1: len 4; hex 8000a6ab; asc     ;;
 2: len 4; hex 000283c7; asc     ;;
 3: len 4; hex 0001e1bb; asc     ;;
 .....    

*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 3770369751, ACTIVE 0 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
5 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 7 row lock(s), undo log entries 6
MySQL thread id 594879, OS thread handle 140461163738880, query id 1343761256 172.16.11.48 fe update
INSERT INTO hourly_creative_stats (date_hour,creative_id,campaign_id,placement_id,account_id,won) values (date_format('2020-01-01 06:56:20.0','%Y-%m-%d %H'),123319,164807,42667,3,1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE won=won+values(won)
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 1558 page no 909823 n bits 120 index PRIMARY of table `ubimo`.`hourly_creative_stats` trx id 3770369751 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap
Record lock, heap no 12 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 22; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 5; hex 99a5426000; asc   B` ;;
 1: len 4; hex 8000a6ab; asc     ;;
 2: len 4; hex 000283c7; asc     ;;
 3: len 4; hex 0001e1bb; asc     ;;
 4: len 6; hex 0000e0bb46d7; asc     F ;;
 5: len 7; hex 0700003b670507; asc    ;g  ;;
 6: len 4; hex 00000024; asc    $;;
 ....

*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (1)
```

The table schema is:

```
CREATE TABLE `hourly_creative_stats` (
  `date_hour` datetime NOT NULL,
  `account_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `placement_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `campaign_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `creative_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `bid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `won` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY `date_hour`,`placement_id`,`campaign_id`,`creative_id`),
  INDEX (`campaign_id`),
  INDEX (`account_id`, `date_hour`)
);
```

Comment: You should add the structure of your `hourly_creative_stats` table. You can use `SHOW CREATE TABLE hourly_creative_stats` to do it.

Comment: The `SQL`'s of those transactions might also help. My guess is: you are inserting into/updating the `account` `campaign`, `creative`, `placement` and `hourly_creative_stats` tables in a random order. In such a case it is easy for a deadlock, when two transactions are waiting for each other's locks.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz there is an SQL of the insertions. search for `INSERT INTO hourly_creative_stats ...` statement

Comment: Yes, you gave two SQL statements in your question. However they could not alone cause a deadlock: MySQL would simply wait for the second one to execute and then will execute the first. There are other SQL statements in the transaction and they caused MySQL to lock several rows in your database. Did you post the entire log message?

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz I think I posted all the relevant info from the innodb status log. I will check whether the transactions contains more statements....

Comment: Still waiting for the `CREATE TABLE`.  To help you, we need to know the `PRIMARY KEY`, other `UNIQUE` keys, and possibly other things.  Also, were there other statements in each of the transactions?

Comment: Thanks, I've added the schema description. I will look into transactions tomorrow....

Comment: We are creating multiple statement objects from the same connection object (using mysql C++ client). I am assuming that each statement object creates its own transaction.  Assuming this I do not see any other statements in the transaction besides `INSERT INTO` with multiple values

Comment: These articles explain the issue:
[1](https://programming.vip/docs/insert-on-duplicate-deadlock-one-time-investigate-and-analysis-process.html)
[2](https://medium.com/@brunojorge11/https-medium-com-brunojorge11-mysql-deadlock-insert-on-duplicate-key-update-76aa246bae72)

Answer (score 0):

Possible causes:

1) Auto increment allocation clash. Look at auto increment lock modes.

2) Are you running this in a virtual machine or in AWS RDS? Virtualization in a host that is overbooked or has noisy neighbours can cause weird clock jitter which can upset the timing of concurrent operations sufficiently to cause spurious deadlocks even where there is theoretically no way for a deadlock to arise. I have seen this in RDS many times, especially on smaller and t class instances.

Comment: (There is no `AUTO_INCREMENT` on that table.)

Answer (score 0):

Please show use all the SQL between the `BEGIN` and the `COMMIT`.

A possible solution:  Make the entire transaction run faster (by seemingly unrelated optimations)

A fallback:  Be ready to catch the deadlock and replay the entire transaction.  This should be implemented regardless.  Even if you get rid of one deadlock, another can pop up.

More discussion on Summary Tables.  Your IODKU approach is reasonable, however my document presents other ways.  They may be of interest.